# App Routing method when login is required causing white screen and login screen to appear on each load

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-router

I am trying to device my strategy for the best way to route through my app, knowing that a person needs to login in order to access a bulk of the app. Right now, my routes are setup like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/app/tabs/home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
];
```

I am running into a problem that each time my app loads (and you have previously authenticated), there is a slight delay in the loading, which causing a white screen to appear, then my login screen appears, then you are routed to the correct destination. Currently, I am using an AuthGuard on the routes, and I use an Obersvable to see if a user has been authenticated, and if not, then redirect them to the login.

```
this.auth.isAuthenticated.subscribe((value) => {
   if (!value) {
     return this.router.navigate(['/login']);
   }
});
```

I believe this may have something to do with some items being loading out of sequence.

My auth service is loaded in my app.component.ts as the platform loads:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
   this.splashScreen.hide();
   this.auth.load();
});
```

And in my auth.service.ts, this is the load function:

```
load() {
  this.isAuthenticated.next(false);
  this.getToken().then(token => {
    if (token && token !== '') {
      this.isAuthenticated.next(true);
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
  });
```

Any thoughts on where I should be looking at what is causing the load sequence issue and why my login screen flashes up on each load of the app?
}

**EDIT**

I believe the issue my be a symptom the `isAuthenticated` BehaviorSubject in my Auth Service.

I changed my AuthGuard code to:

```
this.auth.isAuthenticated.subscribe((value) => {
        if (!value) {
          console.log("failed");
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
      });

      return true;
```

And each time the app reloads, I am seeing the `failed` message in the console. Is something loading out of sequence with the Observable?

Comment: Pretty hard to tell what's wrong, but what happens if you replace `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` with `canLoad: [AuthGuard]` in `app` route object? Also make sure that `AuthGuard` implements the `CanLoad` interface.

Comment: @AndreiGătej, I made a quick EDIT to the bottom of my original post. I tried the canLoad as well, same results.

Comment: I mentioned in my answer `this.isAuthenticated.next(false);` is being set on load, `this.auth.isAuthenticated.subscribe((value)` will get false immediately and redirect you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your requirement is that you want to check the user authentication before hiding the splash screen,  I suggest moving the splash screen hide code into your auth.load() method

```js
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   this.statusBar.styleLightContent();
   // this call will be moved into your auth
   //this.splashScreen.hide();
   this.auth.load();
});
```

```js
// init with null
isAuthenticated = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);

load() {
   // don't set it to false..
   // wherever you initialize it, set it to null for default value
  // this.isAuthenticated.next(false);
  this.getToken().then(token => {
    if (token && token !== '') {
      this.isAuthenticated.next(true);
    } else {
      this.isAuthenticated.next(false);
      // this navigate probably isn't needed since you are doing it in your guards already, but I don't have all of your code to determine that
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
    this.splashScreen.hide();  // you'll need to import it in your service for it to work
  }).catch(error => {
    // also, in case there is an error you probably also want to hide the splash screen
    this.splashScreen.hide();
});
}
```

Also, you are setting `isAuthenticated.next(false)` when you load so your route guard will always fail and redirect to the loading screen.

If `isAuthenticated` is a BehaviorSubject you can initialize it to `null` and in your route guard check if its `null` and wait for an explicit `true` or `false` value before redirecting.

Updated Auth Guard

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private auth: SomeAuthService, private router: Router) {}
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated.pipe(
       // skip initial "null" value, because that means we didn't finish our auth check
       filter(val => val !== null)),
       // now we will map the true/false response here
       map(isAuthenticated => {
         if (isAuthenticated) {
           return true
         } else {
            // build a URLTree pointing to /login
           // you need to import Router from angular 
            return this.router.parseUrl("/login")
         }
       })


  }
```

Comment: I just added an EDIT to my original post.

Comment: Updated to show a better guard example, an how to init the behavior subject as null.  You may need to fix some imports, and you also don't have all your code posted so I made some assumptions.